# Using anacron in cronie on Gentoo - Doesn't run?

Tags: linux, cron

This is the system crontab on a Gentoo system with `cronie` installed, with the `anacron` use flag enabled:

```
59  *  * * *    root    [ ! -x /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.hourly
9  3  * * *     root    [ ! -x /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.daily
19 4  * * 6     root    [ ! -x /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.weekly
29 5  1 * *     root    [ ! -x /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.monthly
*/10  *  * * *  root    [ ! -x /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && { test -x /usr/sbin/run-crons && /usr/sbin/run-crons ; }
```

It makes sure that `/etc/cron.hourly/0anacron` is not present before running anything, because anacron will do the cron.* scripts.  Which it is:

```
 # ls -la /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron 
 -rwxr-x--- 1 root root 448 May 11 23:46 /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron
```

Ok so how does anacron run?  It's helper script is in cron.hourly, but nothing in cron.hourly gets executed if the helper script is present.

I can't find any evidence it has ever run.  It is a chicken and egg.

Comment: I went back to vixie-cron after a few days of no success finding an answer to this.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand it, cronie's anacron is triggered by cron by executing `/etc/cron.hourly/0anacron`. But this never happens due to lines 1 and 5 from crontab (they are run only in case 0anacron is not executable).

I fixed this by changing `/etc/crontab` to following

```
59  *  * * *      root  run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
#59  *  * * *     root  [ ! -x /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.hourly
#9  3  * * *      root  [ ! -x /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.daily
#19 4  * * 6      root  [ ! -x /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.weekly
#29 5  1 * *      root  [ ! -x /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.monthly
#*/10  *  * * * root    [ ! -x /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && { test -x /usr/sbin/run-crons && /usr/sbin/run-crons ; }
```

Line 1 makes sure that scripts in `/etc/cron.hourly` are executed by regular cron every hour (without lastrun file check).

I commented removal of lastrun files for daily, weekly and montly out, because they are run via anacron (defined in `/etc/anacrontab`).

Comment: Yeah, that is effectively how to fix it, but I am more curious about what the intention was.  Really, you don't even need `cron.hourly` to run, as it will get run when anacron eventually runs.  Just running anacron every few minutes (if it isn't running) would do it.  I guess they just didn't finish implementing it.

Comment: Well it seems that cronie implements anacron via cron-triggered job (see [README.anacron](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/cronie.git/tree/README.anacron#n122)). So you need either `cron.hourly` or explicit call of `0anacron` wrapper or directly `anacron -s`.